# Binding Command Not found Error

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, icommand

I am not using any particular library for this. I have a Listview in page and on its click I want to call a command named DemoCommand but as I bind my ViewModel to page it shows error command not found. My Xaml code is.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding OrdersObject}">
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding data.orders}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DueOrderTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchItemStyle}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DemoCommand}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

My binding code is

```
var OrdersObj = new ViewModels.OrdersVM();

            await OrdersObj.GetOrders("cancel");
            this.DataContext = OrdersObj;
```

And my View Model code is

```
class OrdersVM
{
    public Models.DueOrderM OrdersObject { get; set; }

    async public Task<Boolean> GetOrders(string order_type)
    {
       OrdersObject=//from API
    }
    RelayCommand<Models.OOrderM> _demoCommand;

    public RelayCommand<Models.OOrderM> DemoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_demoCommand == null)
            {
                _demoCommand = new RelayCommand<Models.OOrderM>((itemParam) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(itemParam);
                });
            }
            return _demoCommand;
        }
        set { _demoCommand = value; }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself after looking few examples none of which were working I got the solution myself according to which I needed to change only my Xaml code. updated code is

```
<ListView x:Name="lstItem" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersObject.data.orders}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DueOrderTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchItemStyle}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstItem}" Command="{Binding DemoCommand}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

Important thing I noted was naming of listview in command parameter and need to assign it using x:Name then it worked else it did not work. Hope it helps someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would set `DataContext` not in 'code behind' but in XAML

   ```
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   mc:Ignorable="d" 
   DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
   d:DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
   ```
2. You set `OrdersObject` as `DataContext` to the Grid, so try `RelativeSources` so your Command-Binding can *see* the ViewModel again.

Comment: As I need to get data from API so I need to call the method for that first and I could not find a way for this in Xaml that's why I did this.

Comment: I could not implement it. Can you please share a code sample.

Comment: Add MVVM Light through nuget to your project, you will get a sample implementation for a ViewModelLocator and it is well documented.

Comment: I don't want to use any libraries for this. I want to complete this without having to use any libraries or framework.